# Prepare "Install OS X El Capitan.app" for Virtualbox

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, osx-el-capitan

I'm following [these steps](http://blog.frd.mn/install-os-x-10-10-yosemite-in-virtualbox/) to create a DMG file which can be used with VirtualBox. Unfortunately the same steps won't work for `Install OS X El Capitan.app`. The generated image is not bootable from Virtualbox and drops to an emergency EFI shell.
How can I prepare `Install OS X El Capitan.app` to work with Virtualbox?
Installing Yosemite as a VM and then upgrading works but I want to avoid this extra step and do a clean El Capitan install.

Answer (score 8):

The instructions below, found on [1], worked for me after a download of El Capitan from the App Store.

```
hdiutil attach "/Applications/Install OS X El Capitan.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg" -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/esd
hdiutil create -o ElCapitan3.cdr -size 7316m -layout SPUD -fs HFS+J
hdiutil attach ElCapitan3.cdr.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/iso
asr restore -source /Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.dmg -target /Volumes/iso -noprompt -noverify -erase
rm /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation/Packages 
cp -rp /Volumes/esd/Packages /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Installation
cp -rp /Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.chunklist /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/
cp -rp /Volumes/esd/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/
hdiutil detach /Volumes/esd
hdiutil detach /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System
hdiutil convert ElCapitan3.cdr.dmg -format UDTO -o ElCapitan3.iso
mv ElCapitan3.iso.cdr ElCapitan3.iso
```

[1] http://anadoxin.org/blog/creating-a-bootable-el-capitan-iso-image.html

Comment: Mhh, this drops me to an EFI shell with VirtualBox 5.0.6

Comment: Seems to be working in VirtualBox 5.0.10. Another tutorial for Yosemite which I tried to adapt for El Capitan didn't work but this one did.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? I am also dropping to an EFI shell

Comment: Did you change the [System] > [Chipset] setting to PIIX3? Also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198737/install-el-capitan-in-virtual-box-for-testing-purposes/211722#211722